# Procedure Chamada na DLL recebendo valor desconhecido

Tags: delphi, dll

Estou estudando a utilização de DLL, criei uma enviando duas variáveis inteiras, mais especificamente 3 e 10536. Debugando a DLL verifico que na procedure que estou chamando e que recebe estas duas variáveis, elas estão com valores completamente diferentes dos que enviei.

**Chamada** Explicitamente

```
idMestre := 3;
idFunc   := 10536;

if (qryMvFol_M.RecordCount > 0) then
begin
   Handle := LoadLibrary('Calc_Encargos.DLL');
   if (Handle = 0) then
   begin
      Informando('Calc_Encargos.DLL não encontrada.');
      Exit;
   end
   else
   begin
     mPrepara_Para_Calcular := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'Prepara_Para_Calcular');
     mPrepara_Para_Calcular(idMestre, idFunc);
     FreeLibrary(Handle);
   end;
end;
```

**Procedure DLL**

```
procedure Prepara_Para_Calcular(idMestre, idFunc:Integer); stdcall;
begin
{  Aqui chega idMestre = 1524722
              idFunc   = 54771

Não estou entendendo  
}
  try
     Ler_Conecao_Banco;

     qryWork := TFDQuery.Create(nil);

     strSQL := ' select MF.ID_PD, MF.TOTAL'+
               '   from FOLHA_MOV_F MF'+
               '  where MF.ID_REG_MESTRE  = '+FmtInt(idMestre)+
               '    and MF.ID_FUNCIONARIO = '+FmtInt(idFunc)+
               '  union all'+
               ' select MV.ID_PD, MV.TOTAL'+
               '   from FOLHA_MOV_V MV'+
               '  where MV.ID_REG_MESTRE  = '+FmtInt(idMestre)+
               '    and MV.ID_FUNCIONARIO = '+FmtInt(idFunc);

     Prepara_wQuery(qryWork, 'RH', strSQL, '');

     if (qryWork.RecordCount > 0) then
        Erro(IntToStr(qryWork.RecordCount))
     else
        Erro('Sem registro neste filtro');

  finally
     qryWork.Destroy;
  end;
end;
```

O que pode estar causando isto?

Answer (score 1):

Desculpas

Na tipificação da procedure na minha aplicação esqueci de informar a palavra reservada *stdcall* no final da definição, assim:

type
TPrepara_Para_Calcular = procedure (idMestre, idFunc:Integer); **stdcall**;

Resolvido

Comment: Marca como resolvido